# How do I override the automatic address assignments on the loopback device?

Tags: linux, networking, loopback, iproute2

**Background**

On modern linux systems the preferred way of managing network interfaces, ip addresses and routes, and related things is tools from the `iproute2` package.

I am trying to set up a somewhat exotic network configuration wherein I use addresses in the loopback address space on virtual ethernet adapters which connect different network namespaces within one machine.  In order for this to work, I need to change the configuration of the loopback device. Configured automatically, the loopback device has the following state:

```
# ip addr show dev lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see, the interface grabs ahold of the entire `127.0.0.0/8` block, and all packets in the block are routed onto this device. In order to make some subset of the block routable to my virtual ethernet devices, I need to make `lo`'s claim narrower, so it resembles the following:

```
# ip addr show dev lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/12 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is easy enough to do, you simply raise the interface, and use the following commands to change the IP addresses attached to it:

```
ip addr del 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
ip addr add 127.0.0.1/12 dev lo
```

This will also update the routing information, so only `127.0.0.1/12 (127.0.0.0 through 127.15.255.255)` will route to `lo`. This is desirable.

The problem is, whenever you raise a loopback interface, no matter whether it has addresses configured already or not and no matter what those addresses are, it will **always** rebind its default addresses.  So, every time `lo` is lowered and raised manually, or a loopback interface is created from scratch (e.g. in a new network namespace), I need to jump on it and modify its configured addresses.

**Question**

Is there a way I can override this behavior somehow?  I am totally fine with having systemwide loopback configuration that defaults to `127.0.0.1/12` instead of `127.0.0.1/8`, but I would also settle for any workaround that doesn't require me to hover over all of the loopback devices in every namespace like a helicopter, polling them to make sure their addresses are right.

I've looked into [how exactly `iproute2` goes about raising and lowering interfaces](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/main/ip/iplink.c#L1318) and unfortunately it looks like it's just passing the UP flag into an ioctl with no frills or fanfare whatsoever, which implies to me that this behavior may be coming from somewhere deeper within the kernel's device configuration, and might possibly even be hardcoded. I'm not against solving this stupid problem with an extremely technical solution involving recompiling kernel modules or something similarly extravagant but I'd love to know if there's a configuration tweak or workaround that accomplishes what I need before I do that. Can anyone shed some light on where this behavior is coming from, and how to bypass it?

Comment: "I am trying to set up a somewhat exotic network configuration wherein I use addresses in the loopback address space on virtual ethernet adapters which connect different network namespaces" That violates RFC6890, so even if you manage to do it, expect trouble elsewhere. Any particular reason you cannot use private IP ranges for that, like everyone else?

Comment: Trying to use 127/8 for any kind of routing is just going to break things.

Comment: While I'm also curious where the configuration comes from, I agree that 127/8 is probably one of the worst choices for a network. If you ran out of RFC1918 addresses, there's 100.16.0.0/10 and a perfectly good 240.0.0.0/4 out there.

Comment: For clarification, what I have so far works perfectly fine and I can share the setup I'm using if you're interested. This is only for internal routing on a single physical machine (e.g. between containers), and the reason I don't want to use other private addresses is I've got other things running in a variety of places and I don't want to create dead spots in what networks are available elsewhere on my machine that I'll have to work around in the future

Comment: Setup for those curious https://gist.github.com/TheWug/2d59f0e2f789f115e94152b1516d6cba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this comes from systemd (or other init systems, if you're using something else).

[This code shows how it is initialized](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/shared/loopback-setup.c) and right now it isn't possible to change any of this behavior.

Comment: Creating a new network namespace, with no visibility from host's systemd, gets an lo interface. It inherits 127.0.0.1 and ::1 whenever it's brought up. delete them and down/up: inherited again. Looks like a kernel feature rather than a systemd feature.

Answer (score 0):

The addresses on the loopback device *lo* are automatically added by the kernel whenever the interface is brought up, as seen in the source excerpts from kernel 5.10 below.

Relevant part for IPv4 and `127.0.0.1` aka [`INADDR_LOOPBACK`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/in.h?h=v5.10#n295) in [`net/ipv4/devinet.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/devinet.c?h=v5.10#n1551):

> ```c
>   case NETDEV_UP:
>       if (!inetdev_valid_mtu(dev->mtu))
>           break;
>       if (dev->flags & IFF_LOOPBACK) {
>           struct in_ifaddr *ifa = inet_alloc_ifa();
>
>           if (ifa) {
>               INIT_HLIST_NODE(&ifa->hash);
>               ifa->ifa_local =
>                 ifa->ifa_address = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
>               ifa->ifa_prefixlen = 8;
>               ifa->ifa_mask = inet_make_mask(8);
>               in_dev_hold(in_dev);
>               ifa->ifa_dev = in_dev;
>               ifa->ifa_scope = RT_SCOPE_HOST;
>               memcpy(ifa->ifa_label, dev->name, IFNAMSIZ);
>               set_ifa_lifetime(ifa, INFINITY_LIFE_TIME,
>                        INFINITY_LIFE_TIME);
>               ipv4_devconf_setall(in_dev);
>               neigh_parms_data_state_setall(in_dev->arp_parms);
>               inet_insert_ifa(ifa);
>           }
>       }
> ```

Relevant part for IPv6 and `::1` aka [`IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK_INIT`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv6/addrconf_core.c?h=v5.10#n215) in [`net/ipv6/addrconf.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv6/addrconf.c?h=v5.10#n3141):

> ```c
> static void init_loopback(struct net_device *dev)
> {
>   struct inet6_dev  *idev;
>
>   /* ::1 */
>
>   ASSERT_RTNL();
>
>   idev = ipv6_find_idev(dev);
>   if (IS_ERR(idev)) {
>       pr_debug("%s: add_dev failed\n", __func__);
>       return;
>   }
>
>   add_addr(idev, &in6addr_loopback, 128, IFA_HOST);
> }
> ```

also called whenever the [loopback interface](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv6/addrconf.c?h=v5.10#n3584) is [brought up](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv6/addrconf.c?h=v5.10#n3517).

One can still add an other address instead such as 127.0.0.1/12 and remove the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1/8 as OP already wrote:

```
ip address add 127.0.0.1/12 dev lo scope host
ip address delete 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
```

but if the interface is brought down, then back up, this address will be put back by the kernel (in addition to the added one).

Also some kernel parts might have leftover with hardcoded use of 127.0.0.0/8 (actually I could only find a rarely happening example with [netfilter's h323 ALG helper](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat_h323.c?h=v5.10#n109), but I might have missed something).

So kernel has to be altered to change this behavior.